# No viable overload for '=' when there is an operator

Tags: c++, vector, iterator, operator-overloading

```
struct myType{
public:    

    myType operator=(const myType &value){
        return value;
    };

};
```

myType has an operator overload for = but when it is called in the JSON class at `it = js.allInfo.begin();` compiler throws: "No viable overload for '='"

```
class JSON{

private:
vector<myType> allInfo;

public:    

friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &os,const JSON &js)
{
    vector<myType>::iterator it;

    for(it = js.allInfo.begin(); it != js.allInfo.end();it++){
        cout << "this is the info "<<(it->getNAME()) << endl;
    }
    return os;
};
```

What should I change in the overload= to fix this problem

Comment: Usually the return type for the assignment operator is a reference to that type, in this case it would be `myType&`. You are returning `myType` from `operator=` and not `myType&`.   Don't know if that will help you...

Comment: I already do that const myType &value, it is the same as const myType& value, if it is that what you mean

Comment: No, `const` is correct for the argument, but not for the return type.

Comment: `myType& operator=(const myType &value) { /*copy the data from value into this */; return *this; }`. Note the return type and what is the return value (not the original, but `*this`)

Comment: `js.allinfo.begin()` is a member of vector  , nothing to do with `myType`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're trying to iterate a const object (const JSON &js) with a non-const iterator.

Use a const iterator:

```
vector<myType>::const_iterator it;
```

Better yet, use the keyword "auto" to automatically get the proper type:

```
auto it = js.allInfo.begin()
```

Comment: Even better, use a range-for loop.